# In Usual arithmetic conversions, the results of unsigned integer and signed integer operations differ on different compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, mingw

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    assert(typeid(1L + 1U) == typeid(long));
    std::cout << typeid(1L + 1U).name();
}
```

I use the built-in mingw of clion or the built-in msvc or clang of visual studio  on windows. The running result is unsigned long, but on the clang or gcc of linux, the running result is long.

How do I get the result of long on windows?

Comment: `long` is 32 bits on Windows and 64 bits on Linux. Whether it's wider than `int` affects the result.

Comment: to reason about this you have to know what the c++ standard says about three topics: integer types, type inference rules of integer literals and integer promotion rules

Answer (score -1):

The difference in the size of `long` between Windows and Linux can indeed affect the result.

If you want to ensure consistent behavior across platforms, you should consider using fixed-width integer types from the `<cstdint>` header. For example, you can use `int32_t` to ensure a 32-bit signed integer:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int32_t result = 1L + static_cast<int32_t>(1U);
    assert(typeid(result) == typeid(int32_t));
    std::cout << typeid(result).name();
}
```

By using fixed-width integer types, you explicitly specify the size of the integer, making your code more platform-independent. In this case, int32_t ensures a `32-bit` signed integer regardless of the platform.

Comment: `assert(typeid(result) == typeid(int32_t));` seems pretty pointless since you've declared `result` to be an `int32_t`. Make it  `auto result = ...;` and the assertion will most probably fail since the result of `1L + static_cast<int32_t>(1U);` will be `long` and `int32_t` is most probably `int`.

Comment: "ensures a 32-bit signed integer regardless of the platform: -- not quite; it ensures a 32-bit signed integer **if** the compiler provides that as one of the standard types. If the compiler doesn't have a 32-bit signed integer `int32_t` won't exist.